# Почему PHP cURL работает только по понедельникам

Tags: php, веб-сервер, php-curl

Суть проблемы в том что расширение cURL на нашем сайте выдает ошибку *"В процессе тестирования соединения с сервером обновлений, PHP расширение cURL вернуло следующую ошибку:
Curl error code: 77. Error:"*

Но по понедельникам ошибки нет. Скрипт проводит авторизацию на удаленном портале и запускает процесс обновления информации между двух ресурсов. Обращался к разработчикам удаленного портала, они ответили, что проблема с нашей стороны. Все нужные компоненты CURL установлены и OpenSSL.

Comment: Потомучто в понедельник программистов мама родила =)

Comment: @Bloom Я уже действительно так начинаю считать.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/reinaldomendes/97fb2ce8a606ec813c4b

Comment: @zalex  эти конфиги так же стоят